# HackerRank - Picking Numbers

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and it's my first ever question here.

I've been trying to solve this challenge https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=true for three consecutive days but still got 3/10 test cases failed.

Here the algorithm I use:

1. For each element in the main array create a subarray where all elements are equal or no more or less by 1
2. Resulting number of subarrays (which equals to the number of elements in the first array) are checked for validity meaning that each element is equal or no more or less by 1
3. Find the longest valid subarray and return it's size

Here is the code for the solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'pickingNumbers' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY a as parameter.
     */

    public static int pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a) {
        int maxLength = 0;
        boolean isValidArray = false;
        List<Integer> subarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            subarray = findValidSubarray(a, a.get(i));
            isValidArray = arrayValidityCheck(subarray);
            if ((isValidArray) && (subarray.size() > maxLength)) {
                maxLength = subarray.size();
            }
        }
        return maxLength;
    }

    private static List<Integer> findValidSubarray(List<Integer> array, Integer integer) {
        List<Integer> subarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int elem : array) {
            if ((elem == integer) || (elem + 1 == integer) || (elem == integer + 1)) {
                subarray.add(elem);
            }
        }
        return subarray;
    }
//check that all elements are equal or not more or less than 1 to each other
    private static boolean arrayValidityCheck(List<Integer> subarray) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < subarray.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < subarray.size(); j++) {
                if ((subarray.get(i) == subarray.get(j)) || (subarray.get(i) + 1 == subarray.get(j)) || (subarray.get(i) == subarray.get(j) + 1)) {
                    isValid = true;
                } else {
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isValid) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] firstMultipleInput = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(firstMultipleInput[0]);

        List<Integer> a = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(toList());
        bufferedReader.close();

        int result = Result.pickingNumbers(a);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Sample test case data which is failing:

> 100

and

> 14 18 17 10 9 20 4 13 19 19 8 15 15 17 6 5 15 12 18 2 18 7 20 8 2 8 11
> 2 16 2 12 9 3 6 9 9 13 7 4 6 19 7 2 4 3 4 14 3 4 9 17 9 4 20 10 16 12
> 1 16 4 15 15 9 13 6 3 8 4 7 14 16 18 20 11 20 14 20 12 15 4 5 10 10 20
> 11 18 5 20 13 4 18 1 14 3 20 19 14 2 5 13

Valid answer:

> 15

My answer:

> 13

I'm out of ideas where the bug is here.
Could you please help me?

PS: I'm aware that this algorithm is not optimal. Any optimization tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would point out, the positions of the numbers in the array are irrelevant. Knowing the count of each number, which can be found in a single pass, it is possible to find the max of the sum of counts of two adjacent numbers in a single pass through the counts. There is no need to create any subarrays.

Comment: It sounds like a much better version of the existing algo. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As pointed out in the comments it is sufficient to do one type of check and only check if the other elements are 1 larger than the first element in the check. Answer modified accordingly

Your problem is that when you build your subarray, you allow numbers in it that are both 1 higher and 1 lower than the first element you start with.
You then later try to clean up your results by re-validating your generated arrays, but this will not fix the problem that you will not generate any all possible valid subarrays with your method.

My proposal to fix your code would be:

1. Modify your `findValidSubarray` method so that only allows elements that are 1 higher in it. (The cases where lower numbers would be allowed in will be handled in other iteration when that lower number is the starting element for the iteration)
2. remove the `arrayValidityCheck` as this one will no longer be needed as the above will directly only produce valid subarrays.

Modified findValidSubarray method:

```
private static List<Integer> findValidSubarray(final List<Integer> array, final Integer integer) {
    final List<Integer> subarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (final int elem : array) {
         if ((elem == integer) || (elem + 1 == integer)) {
             subarray.add(elem);
         }
    }
    return subarray;
}
```

Calling that method:

```
public static int pickingNumbers(final List<Integer> a) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    List<Integer> subarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        subarray = findValidSubarray(a, a.get(i));
        if ((subarray.size() > maxLength)) {
            maxLength = subarray.size();
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if both calls are needed? I think it will get two times the same subarrays - the subarray for `x` allowing elements `x+1` is the same subarray as for `y` allowing `y-1`  if `y = x + 1` (or have I missed some *border* case?)

Comment: @user16320675 now that i think about it, you are probably right.

Comment: "(The cases where lower numbers would be allowed in will be handled in other iteration when that lower number is the starting element for the iteration)" this part was hard for me to understand by now I see the logic behind it. Thank you everyone for the answers!